# /boot df -h and ls -lh do not match

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, boot

Redhat Centos7

I've tried searching the internet for far too long to find a solution. my /boot partition has an issue.

I can't find what's taking up space.

[this is my df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqfkO.png)
it shows -boot taking up 274M 97%

[this is my ls -lh on /boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgbTb.png)
It shows 33M.

[this is my df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMaPW.png)
I see talk about inodes but that doesn't seem to be an issue for me. I'm only using 1%

Nothing of large importance showing up with an "lsof|grep -i deleted", some apache/php files in /tmp

Other options I read on the internet talk about unmounting but I can't unmount /boot. Please send help

EDIT: also wanted to add my du -sh * on /boot
[It matches up with the 33M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D52WE.png)

Comment: Just to add to this I just tried to umount /boot. ls -a shows nothing in /boot. I'm thinking this is an issue with /dev/sda1? But at this point I'm not sure what to even look for. and why when its mounted the files shown du -sf and df -h don't match up

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking the same things / you cannot compare that.

ls as you use it shows only what is on the directory (not subdirectories)

du -i shows inodes not files sizes

df -h shows Go taken by files

that's why they are different tools :)

Comment: I added an edit to show what du -sh shows on boot. Still a huge size discrepancy. with my df -h showing boot this full i'm not not able to update the kernel.  Correct on the inodes. I've seen responses to issues along these lines that inodes also take up space when in use so I wanted to add that in so people will see it doesn't make up for the difference